# Why do contracts have the ability to know whether the caller is a contract?

Tags: contract-design, evm

I see a lot of contracts around that block calls from other contracts. Seems to me like this prevents a lot of possible integration scenarios. Why was this ability built into the protocol?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it was a security tradeoff, an attacker would use an adversarial contract to attack in a hypothetical scenario. Cutting off calls from contracts is a sure way to stop at least one vector. Also integrating without another protocols permission is a bad manners move in crypto from the view of many. If you really wanted to integrate, you could and SHOULD contact the project team in question.

Comment: as it is now, integration is not prevented, but it's less safe because you have to rely on some code outside of EVM